# UK Clean Slate policy

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, student-visa, uk-visa, uk-visitor-visa

I am a US citizen and had few minor immigration problems one time when I tried to enter back in 2018 but they let me in after all. Last year in 2019 I tried to enter again and they let me in with no problems. Does my last successful entry wipe my slate clean? I will apply for a tier 4 and I am just very nervous regarding my entry back in 2018 when they almost considered me a frequent visitor

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the 'minor immigration problems'? Were there some issues in your background which raised some flags?

Comment: @Aym You were apparently suspected of attempting to live in the UK via a series of more or less consecutive Short Term Student visas / visa-free entry. This is against the Rules governing that type of entry. A Tier 4 visa is a different kettle of fish, your application should be judged on its own merits, providing they’re convinced you’ll adhere to the conditions of the visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clean slate. Sorry. There is a *general* guidance that for some visa types, certain transgressions older than ten years may be disregarded at the case worker's discretion. That doesn't seem to apply to your case, and you will have to give some extra explanations as to why the UK can trust that you won't violate the terms of the Tier 4 visa. The fact that you entered again, and presumably followed the rules, does bode well for you though. This not only gives you a positive mark on your recent immigration history, it means that whatever happened in 2018 wasn't so bad as to invoke a ban or leave any major flags on your record.